# MySQL Function eat too much CPU

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cpu-usage

When I'm executing a function in MySQL Query Browser it gives error message this is "
"Script line: 3 Lost connection to MySQL server during query", even i can't drop it. when i'm executing or trying to drop it out my Query browser got stuck. the function code is given below

The argument should like this - ('52,53,50')

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `split_string` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `split_string`(sStrMain VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
DECLARE n,l INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE L1,str,temp,L2,res,Final_res VARCHAR(255);


SET str = sStrMain;

WHILE str !='' DO
  SET L1 = SUBSTRING(str,1,LOCATE(',',str)-1);
  SET res = lookup_code(L1);
  SET Final_res = CONCAT_WS(',',Final_res,res);
  SET temp = REPLACE(str,SUBSTRING(str,1,L1,'');
  SET str = temp;
  SET temp = '';
  SET n = n + 1;
END WHILE;


RETURN Final_res;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I'm going to use this function for splitting string by separator(comma) and return me the result.

Comment: Please post the real code you use with c&p. `SET temp = REPLACE(str,SUBSTRING(str,1,L1,'');` is a syntax error. BTW, AFAICT `temp` is unnecessary - you could just do `SET str = REPLACE(...);`.

Comment: Besides, I don't thinK your functionm will be able to do what you want: as it returns only a `varchar`, it converts `50,51,52` to `505152` - I don't think that's what you want...

Comment: What actually should your function do?

Comment: @Devart I'm try to split the string by comma and the exrtacted value will send to another function which get a name(string value) for extracted value. you can see lookup_code(L1). if you have better idea please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this split text procedure -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE split_string(sStrMain VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  SET @strLen := 0;
  SET @i := 1;

  WHILE @strLen < LENGTH(sStrMain)  DO
    SET @str = SUBSTRING_INDEX(sStrMain, ',', @i);
    SET @strLen = LENGTH(@str);
    SET @i = @i + 1;

    SET @res = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str, ',', -1);
    SELECT @res; -- Show a value, call your function here

  END WHILE;
END
```